# formatting text with document.execCommand and browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've put together a compact little bit of code to change the styling of a selection of text.

It almost seems too simple.

Please see my jsfiddle for reference.

I can get this to work in IE10, and FF, but it won't work in IE9 or Safari.

Is there any way to get it to work with those browsers?

Thanks

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yd3u8/27/

```
$(".styleEvent").click(function(e) {
var styleType = e.target.id;
styleEvent(styleType);
```

});

```
function styleEvent(style) {
    document.execCommand(style);
}
```

Comment: I'm using IE9 and its working (tested on your jsfiddle and in a html alone).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function styleEvent(style) {
document.execCommand(style);
if(style=="subscript"){style="line-through";} 
if(style=="superscript"){style="overline";}
if(style=="bold"){document.getElementById('editor').style.fontWeight= "bold";}
document.getElementById('editor').style.textDecoration=style;
}
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/Yd3u8/30/

Comment: thanks for the code but that jsfiddle demo does strange things in the latest version of firefox.